# Why is the graph of a constant, a line?

Tags: graphing-functions

Why is the graph for x=3 (Or C where C is a constant) as a vertical line on the
xy coordinate plane or Y = some C as a horizontal line? Shouldn’t they be points?

Comment: Because for every value of $x$ we have a point $(x,C)$ in the xy-graph.

Comment: When you plot a function $f$ you generate all values $f(a)$ of the function for input value $a$. The plot is the graph of points $(a,f(a))$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They are points: the graph  of x=c is obtained by plotting each possible point in which abscissa equals c; the graph  of y=c is obtained by plotting each possible point in which ordinate equals c. Plot 10 points in each case. What you will get if you plot all possible points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes to the interpretation of Cartesian equations. The graph $(C)$ of equation $f(x, y)=0$ is by definition the set
$$
\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2| f(x,y)=0\}
$$

In particular, the graph of $x=c$ is the set $\{(x, y)|x=c\}=\{(c, y)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ , The case of $y=c$ is analogous.

On a more intuitive level, a point in 2D space (the plane) has 2 degrees of freedom (corresponding to its two coordinates), fixing one of them only takes one degree of freedom which means that the resulting space should be 1-dimensional rather than 0-dimensional.

Comment: I am not sure I quit understand the question